# Harbor push image to Alibaba ACR failed

Tags: alibaba-cloud

Self-built harbor version: v2.0.1-d714b3ea

I created a replication policy to sync images to Alibaba ACR, when the dest repository type is Harbor, the connection test is successful, but when the type is Alibaba ACR, the connection test is failed.

I was able to push image to ACR successfully by execute command "docker push" , but failed when using the harbor replication policy.

Here is the error message in core.log:
**failed to do the prepare work for pushing/uploading resources: http error: code 404, message 404 page not found**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What service type are you using there? I got a similar error once and I think I had the wrong service type selected.

Comment: I used to choose ''Harbor'. After changing to 'Docker Registry', it push successfully.